Is there a way to change 2-finger scroll touchpad speed on Ubuntu 24.04?
Well, it seems that this was impossible in previous versions. So are there any changes in version 24.04?
By the way, I have tried Arch Linux, and the scroll speed can be modified directly in the settings. How is this done, or is there anything different from Ubuntu here?

I have a "speed" option in 'mouse and touchpad' on cinnamon and budgie (ie. gnome2). But it is a dconf setting so you could search for it in dconf-editor.

I have tried Arch Linux, and the scroll speed can be modified directly in the settings Was that GNOME?
